What happens to cards exiled face-down at the end of a game?
I know that face-down spells and permanents must be revealed to my opponent at the end of a game, generally to prove that it was legal to play them face down. Likewise if such an object changes zones, but that's not relevant to my question.

708.9. [...] If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players. At the end of each game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells must be revealed to all players.

I find no such rule for face-down cards which are neither permanents nor spells, such as those exiled by Bomat Courier. Those cards stay exiled face-down even if the Courier changes zones (unless put into hand by its ability, of course), and my understanding is that even at the end of the game I don't have to show these cards to my opponent: I just put them back into my deck, still face-down, so I can shuffle up for game 2. In this way I can avoid giving my opponent free information about what cards are in my deck.
But what about cards exiled face-down by a player other than their owner? Suppose I cast Siphon Insight targeting my opponent, and I exile a card that is somehow very revealing about the kind of deck my opponent is playing - Indomitable Creativity, for example. My opponent concedes soon after, having failed to draw enough lands during the game to do anything impactful. Of course, I have to give the exiled card back to my opponent so they can put it back into their deck for game 2. But do I have to let them look at it? It would be nice if they went into game 2 thinking they still had the element of surprise over me, when in fact they don't.
I don't see any rule saying I have to show them this card, but it's hard to believe that I could refuse. How could I? Insert it into their deck myself, face-down, and give it a couple shuffles before they can get ready for game 2? I feel like if this were the actual rule, I would have heard about it before.
As far as I can tell, the Comprehensive Rules don't address multi-game matches: that's the domain of the MTR. But I can't find anything about this in the MTR either. Is there a definitive rule on this, or is it just common sense that I have to let my opponent see their own cards or what?

Incidentally, 702.143f dictates that foretold cards specifically must be turned face up at end of game, but does not include any other type of face-down card in exile

Yes, your opponent may look at their own cards after each game of a match.
From the Tournament Rules:

2.3 Pregame Procedures

If sideboarding is allowed, players may remove cards from their decks and add cards from their sideboards.

Players shuffle their decks. Steps 1 and 2 may be repeated.

Players present their decks to their opponents for additional shuffling.The sideboard (if any) is also presented at this time.



You may shuffle your opponent's deck, but only after they have sideboarded (which necessarily includes looking at the cards) and their own shuffle. Between the end of one game and the pregame procedure of the next game, players are free to look at their own cards in any way they choose. There is no provision for shuffling the deck as part of the postgame procedure, so there is no way to prevent your opponent from gaining that information.
